# Postback a single item on a Razor ListBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-ajax, html-helper

I have a ListBoxFor helper that is populated with users that have to be verified from a db. I click a single user and then click a submit button. This works fine and sets the admin verified bit in the db to true.

However what I am trying to do is on an item in the list being clicked, a value auto posted back and then I will fill a textarea with the users description. I gather I will use AJAX but have found it hard to get good documentation on using AJAX with HTMLHelpers in the this way.

EDIT: Updated the Model, View and Controller as per suggestions.

Model:

```
public class UserAdminVerifyModel
{
    public SelectList ToBeVerifiedAdmin { get; set; }
    public string[] SelectedUsers { get; set; }
    public List<string> userdesc { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult AdminVerifyListBox()
    {
        UserAdminVerifyModel verifusermodel = new UserAdminVerifyModel();
        verifusermodel.ToBeVerifiedAdmin = GetUsersToBeVerified();
        return View(verifusermodel);            
    }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AdminVerifyListbox", "UserRegLog"))
{
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedUsers, Model.ToBeVerifiedAdmin)
<br /> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit" title="submit" />
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ListBoxFor is used to generate a multiple selection list. This means that you should not be binding it to a simple string property. You should use an array of strings:

```
public class UserAdminVerifyModel
{
    public SelectList ToBeVerifiedAdmin { get; set; }
    public string[] SelectedUsers { get; set; }
    public List<string> userdesc { get; set; }
}
```

and in the view bind the ListBoxFor to the SelectedUsers collection property:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AdminVerifyListbox", "UserRegLog"))
{
    @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedUsers, Model.ToBeVerifiedAdmin)
    <br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" title="submit" />
}
```

Also your `ToBeVerifiedAdmin` is already a SelectList. You should not be calling the constructor once again in your view. This should be done in your controller action which is responsible for populating this `ToBeVerifiedAdmin` property from wherever your information is stored.